# BLToolkit Complex Mapping Using SELECT JOIN

Tags: database, mapping, bltoolkit

Trying to use BLToolkit mapper in my project. There is a thing that I really don't know how to solve , the deal is that I have 2 classes Content and Comment.

```
[MapField("CommentItemId","CommentContent.ContentId")]
public class Comment
{
    [MapField("Comment.CommentId")]
    public int CommentId;

    [Relation(typeof(Content))]
    public Content CommentContent;
}


 public class Content
{
    [MapField("ContentId"),PrimaryKey]
    public int ContentId;

    public IList<Comment> Comments = new List<Comment>();
}
```

Well , looks as simple Complex Mapping as example that everybody saw on BLToolkit.net .
But , I'm trying to use SELECT JOIN query. This is my query.

```
MapResultSet[] sets = new MapResultSet[2];
sets[0] = new MapResultSet(typeof(Content));
sets[1] = new MapResultSet(typeof(Comment));

command = String.Format(@"SELECT con.ContentId,com.CommentId,com.CommentItemId
                           FROM Content as con,Comments as com
                           WHERE (con.ContentId = com.CommentItemId AND con.ContentId {0})", itemid, type);
```

This query returns correct data ( checked with ExecuteReader ). But in MapResultSets there is only Content data , no Comment data ... If i will interchange Content and Comment sets ... I will get only Comment data , and no Content data ... I don't even care about realtions right now , i just want to explain to BLToolkit , that there is data of 2 classes in 1 row.

Comment: Did you happen to solve this problem without custom class with properties of both classes (sort of flat content-comment class)?